# Is the boot process longer when installed on a hard drive than from running on a USB stick?

Tags: boot, usb

I have a Windows 7 Sony Vaio laptop. I have created a bootable USB stick
with Ubuntu 12.04 and have tried Ubuntu and like it. I would like to have it
alongside Windows 7.

When I boot from the USB, I receive lots of messages scrolling by until eventually
the Ubuntu logo appears and Ubuntu starts. The boot takes at least a minute or two. 
My question is, is this long boot process only for the USB boot? If I install from 
the USB, will subsequent Ubuntu startups from my hard drive be quicker, without all the messaging? Or is there a problem with my USB and I need to re-create the USB?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Ubuntu installed on a hard drive starts under a minute or faster ([this site](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/04/performance-ubuntu-13-04-review/) reports 18 seconds). Installed on an SSD -- and I can tell this from my own experience -- it boots up in a few seconds. Furthermore, additional services loaded at boot time or applications loaded in a GUI session [can be disabled](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/06/few-things-to-speed-up-ubuntu/) to shave off a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely vouch for this one, having used both I find my SSD is much much faster. Last time I was running it I checked the differences. They clocked in at:

USB Stick : ~40s
SSD : ~4-5s

As for the scrolling text you could add splash to your grub file at /etc/default/grub to display a wallpaper instead. Don't forget to back this file up however before making any changes. You would change the line too :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Then to make the changes permanent run :

```
update-grub
```

However I would advise doing a test boot before making the changes permanent. To do this just select Ubuntu and press e and the grub screen on start-up. Edit the file as above and then press f10 to start. This way you can try the changes before making them permanent.